# Overload char pointers and string literals

Tags: c++

I'm trying to create a class that will accept (and can disambiguate) string literals from char pointers. When searching this problem the solution provided was to create a 'holder' class that only accepts char pointers:

```
template< typename char_t >
class String
{
    struct holder_t
    {
        const char_t* s;
        holder_t( const char_t* s ) : s(s) {}
        holder_t( char_t* s ) : s(s) {}
    };
public:

    // Construct from string literal
    template< size_t S >
    String( const char_t (&str)[S] )
    {
        std::cout << "String Literal: " << str;
    }

    // Construct from char pointer
    String( holder_t h )
    {
        std::cout << "Char Pointer: " << h.s;
    }
};
```

The big idea is that you should never have to explicitly create instances of this class, it should happen by implicit conversion:

```
void StringFoo( String<char> s )
{
}
```

However this results in compile errors for char pointers, *why isn't the implicit conversion working?*

```
int main()
{
    // Works!
    StringFoo( "literal" );

    // error C2664: 'StringFoo' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'const char *' to 'String<char_t>'
    // with [ char_t=char ]
    // No constructor could take the source type, or constructor overload resolution was ambiguous
    StringFoo( (const char*)"const char ptr" );

    // Works!
    StringFoo( String<char>((const char*)"const char ptr") );

    // error C2664: 'StringFoo' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'char *' to 'String<char_t>'
    // with [ char_t=char ]
    // No constructor could take the source type, or constructor overload resolution was ambiguous
    StringFoo( (char*)"char ptr" );

    // Works!
    StringFoo( String<char>((char*)"const char ptr") );

    return 0;
}
```

This is just a simple pointless example; in my real code I created a class that will hold the hash of the string.

The hash should be generated at compile time if a string literal is passed and calculated at runtime if a char pointer is passed.

However this should be completely transparent to the user who just passes strings around, hashing is done automagically.

Comment: Pointer is not an array!

Comment: The 2nd constructor accepts a holder_t argument, which can be implicitly constructed from a char pointer. This works fine if I explicitly create the instance, I just want it to happen implicitly.

Comment: @sliser A string literal is an array.

Comment: @sliser: Where did anybody say or imply that it was?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the code doesn't work with pointer is that it requires two versions (`char const*` to `holder` and `holder` to `String`. However, implicit conversions will do at most one conversion.

For the purpose you are describing I'd think you can reasonably just distinguish between `char const(&)[N]` and `char const*`: since you always want to compute a hash anyway and just make it is a `constexpr` where possible, making the version taking `char const(&)[N]` a reference should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks for providing a workaround using constexpr, however at the moment I'm stuck with vs 2012 which doesn't support it. Is there any possible way to get it to work without constexpr? If not then I guess I'll fast track upgrading to vs 2013...

Comment: Actually I just tried to just get rid of holder_t and it appears to work, I was so focussed because I read somewhere that you need this trick to distinguish between string literals and char pointers (that string literals always choose the char pointer overload instead) that I didn't think to try it otherwise.

Comment: "The hash should be generated at compile time" "get it to work without constexpr" the two don't seem possible together.

Comment: Are you sure it is computed at compile time? How?

Comment: @n.m. Yes, I inspect with IDA pro but you can just run strings command on your executable and see that the strings you're hashing are not there. Without __forceinline msvc will create a function that will calculate the hash at runtime though... Any attempt at forcing loop unrolling failed, __forceinline + manually unrolled loop works. Will replace with constexpr once I upgrade to vs 2013 though.

Comment: I cannot reproduce what you are claim with either msvc12 or gcc. Consider building a much simpler proof-of-concept.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67420/discussion-between-microcode-and-n-m).

Answer (score 1):

To get from a string literal to a `String` requires two user-defined conversions - one to `holder_t` and another to `String`. But overload resolution only allows you to have one such conversion per argument.